# Creating interactive UI

Tags: c++, menu, menuitem, ncurses

I want to create an interactive menu using ncourses and menu.h
I want to print the content of current directory and then make menu out of it. I am currently going by [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html) tutorial

and tried code

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define CTRLD   4
```

But when i run the program , it does not print the list of files it should. However using the static array like in the works.

What did i do wrong? Did i overlook some mistake?

```
vector<char *> choices;

    DIR *dir;
    dirent *pdir;
    dir=opendir(".");

    while((pdir=readdir(dir)))
    {
        choices.push_back( pdir->d_name );
    }
    closedir(dir);

ITEM **my_items;
    int c;              
    MENU *my_menu;
    int n_choices, i;
    ITEM *cur_item;


    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);


    n_choices = ARRAY_SIZE(choices);
    my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));

    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i)
            my_items[i] = new_item(choices[i], choices[i]);
    my_items[n_choices] = (ITEM *)NULL;

    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);
    mvprintw(LINES - 2, 0, "F1 to Exit");
    post_menu(my_menu);
    refresh();

    while((c = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
    {   switch(c)
        {   case KEY_DOWN:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
                break;
        }
    }   

    free_item(my_items[0]);
    free_item(my_items[1]);
    free_menu(my_menu);
    endwin();
```

Comment: `choices.push_back( pdir->d_name );` pushes onto the `choices` vector an address of a char array the contents of which change every time round the loop.  Try changing `vector<char *> choices;` to `vector<std::string> choices;` and then fixing any compilation errors.  You have also tagged this question C++ so try and get rid on any casts and direct calls to malloc, calloc etc.

Comment: menu.h is C library that does not know string so it would be impossible to conver char * to string , or?

Comment: Assignment eg : `char const * pszChars = "qwer"; std::string str = pszChars;`

Answer (score 0):

The `ARRAY_SIZE` macro only works on arrays. It uses `sizeof`, but the size of a vector object does not depend on the number of elements. It is a constant value that is the same for every vector. The elements are allocated dynamically. If you want the number of elements in a `std::vector`, there's a member function for that.

```
n_choices = choices.size();
```